# How to generate a Hateoas link containing sortBy query parameter(and it's possible values), using Spring Hateoas?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-hateoas

I am having below a controller(just for example) method:

```
@Autowired
EntityLinks entityLinks;

@GetMapping(value = "{userId}", params = "sortBy")
public Resource<User> getUser(@PathVariable Integer userId, @RequestParam String sortBy ){

        Resource<User> userResource = new Resource<>(new User());

        userResource.add(entityLinks.linkToSingleResource(getClass(), userId));    
        return userResource;

}
```

`GET http://localhost:8085/api/v1/test/11?sortBy` returns me:

```
{
    "name": null,
    "email": null,
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8085/api/v1/test/11"
        }
    }
}
```

My concern is, from `"href": "http://localhost:8085/api/v1/test/11"` how could any client(or the person using the API) would guess if `sortBy` query param is required by the API? And what values `sortBy` demands e.g `id`,`name`

Is there any way to generate more helpfull `href`? e.g `"href": "http://localhost:8085/api/v1/test/11{?sortBy=id,name}"`. Means `sortBy` can only accepts `id` and `name`

Answer (score 0):

You can build a `Link` object and add it to `Resource`. Please try :

```
@GetMapping(value = "{userId}", params = "sortBy")
public Resource<User> getUser(@PathVariable Integer userId, @RequestParam String sortBy ){

        Link selfLink = new Link(entityLinks.linkFor(User.class) + "/" + fooId + "{?sortBy=id,name}").withSelfRel();

        Resource<User> resource = new Resource<>(new User());
        resource.add(selfLink);    
        return userResource;
}
```